# Popup modal details cannot show selected values in fullcalendar function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar function, now I am facing a problem to show the selected value in the popup modal box when I've clicked the selected date to show.

For example I choose 11 April 2021, the Tajuk (title) value is `Meeting`, Person Name value is `Janet`. But now my result only show the title value is `Meeting`, `person_name` value cannot show **Janet**. Like below picture:

[image: output]

Actually, I want the expected output like the below picture:

[image: output1]

Below is my coding:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade" style="z-index: 1400;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style=" width: 75%; margin: auto;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="lampiran_content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="loa_type" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div class="row" id="myForm5">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <div id="collapse4" class="body" style="overflow:auto; padding: 20px;">
                                        
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                <label>Tajuk</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4"  id="modal_show">                                         
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value=""/>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="eventID" name="eventID" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                <label>Person Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4"  id="modal_show_person_name">                                         
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_name" name="person_name" value=""/>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="eventID" name="eventID" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="deleteFunc()">Padam</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<script>
//suppose this is array
var arrays = [{
  "title": "All Day Event",
  "person_name": "John",
  "start": "2021-04-15 00:00:00",
  "color": "#40E0D0"
}, {
  "title": "Long Event",
  "person_name": "Winson",
  "start": "2021-05-01 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "title": "Repeating Event",
  "person_name": "Shawn",
  "start": "2021-04-16 00:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Conference",
  "person_name": "David",
  "start": "2021-04-17 00:00:00",
  "color": "#40E0D0"
}, {
  "title": "Meeting",
  "person_name": "Janet",
  "start": "2021-04-11 00:00:00",
  "color": "#000"
}, {
  "title": "Lunch",
  "person_name": "Peter",
  "start": "2021-05-03 00:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Happy Hour",
  "person_name": "Shemain",
  "start": "2021-04-21 00:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Dinner",
  "person_name": "Jane",
  "start": "2021-04-19 00:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}]

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    initialDate: '2021-04-25',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    eventDidMount: function(view) {
      //loop through json array
      $(arrays).each(function(i, val) {
        //find td->check if the title has same value-> get closest daygird ..change color there
        $("td[data-date=" + moment(val.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "] .fc-event-title:contains(" + val.title + ")").closest(".fc-daygrid-event-harness").css("background-color", val.color);
      })
    },
    select: function(arg) {
      $('#createEventModal #startTime').val(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal #endTime').val(arg.end);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');
    },
    eventClick:  function(arg) {
             $('#modal_show > #title').val(arg.event.title);
             $('#modal_show_person_name > #person_name').text(arg.event.person_name);
             $('#modal_show > #eventID').val(arg.event.id);
             $('#calendarModal').modal();
            },
            
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    events: arrays //pass array here
  });

  calendar.render();


});

</script>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Change `$('#modal_show_person_name > #person_name').text(arg.event.person_name)` to `$('#modal_show_person_name > #person_name').val(arg.event.extendedProps.person_name);`

Comment: And read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing carefully to understand why Swati's comment is correct.